# Calculate the rotation between 2 Inertial Measurement Unit (IMU) for each Tait-Bryan angles

Tags: quaternions, euler-angles, imu

The first IMU (called S1) is placed on the shoulder and works as a reference; the other (S2) is placed on the arm. They provide the quaternion of their rotation relative to the absolute reference (magnetic north and gravity vector). The simple idea is that I need to show the Yaw, Pitch and Roll differences between these two (e.g. an ideal abduction/adduction movement should have pitch contributions only). I started using quaternions, by calculating the rotation between the two (conj(q1) * q2) and then converting it to YPR angles by using:

```
# Rotation quaternion q1 = (w,x,y,z)
# unit = sum of squared elements (sqx = x^2, etc.)

yaw = math.atan2(2 * q1[2] * q1[0] - 2 * q1[1] * q1[3], sqx - sqy - sqz + sqw)
pitch = math.asin(2 * (q1[1] * q1[2] + q1[3] * q1[0]) / sqx + sqy + sqz + sqw)  
roll = math.atan2(2 * q1[1] * q1[0] - 2 * q1[2] * q1[3], -sqx - sqy + sqz + sqw)
```

but this doesn't work in my case, since pitch and roll are not consistent in different arm positions. E.g. if relative Yaw is 90 deg, pitch and roll angles are interchanged. E.g. if I apply a pitch rotation to S2, it appears to be a roll rotation (since the rotation is on the y-axis for the reference sensor S1).
How can I avoid this?
Should I simply convert both quaternion to YPR angles and then calculate the difference of each pair (without using the difference between quaternions)? Maybe the "rotation" approach is not correct, since I don't need the inverse transformation but only the actual rotation for each axis?

Comment: I have not checked the math, but the idea seems correct. However, the effect you describe seems to awfully resemble a [Gimbal lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock), which might be the source of your woes?

Comment: I don't know if this can be the case. Because roll and pitch, e.g. with a relative yaw of 90 deg, are perfectly interchanged, I don't see "strange" angles but exactly a 45 deg (for example) in the roll if I rotate by 45 deg the pitch...

Comment: What result do you expect to get? Euler angles in general are not additive, and rotations are order-dependent. E.g., a rotation yaw = 45 followed by pitch = 30, will in general not lead to the same result when combined as rotations (i.e., via quaternion multiplication) as it would if you simply added the angle values. Same applies for the order of operations - rot(a)*rot(b) != rot(b)*rot(a). In this case, rotating yaw by 90 degrees might indeed "interchange" the roll and pitch for transformations applied after the yaw transform, as the "axes" of the coord system effectively changed.